# Insufficient privileges for Dashboards

Tags: dashboard

I was trying to grant access to some of my users who were added into a public group. The users have "Salesforce Platform" user license. The reports are dependent on a custom object.
The access to the dashboard folder is granted by adding the groups, still when one of the user is trying to see the dashboard he is getting "Insufficient Priviledges" error.

Can somebody help me in this? Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Does the platform licence you are using have access to the custom object and the 'Run Reports' privilege?

Comment: How do I check that? Here I am assuming the platform license can access the custom object

Comment: Go to the Profile that the platform licence users are on and look at Object Permissions to see if they have access to that custom object and if not grant permission. However I found a relevant piece of information that I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Just checked: They have the access-
Below are the details: Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the 'Running User' for the dashboard must be a user with the Salesforce Platform licence.

From [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=0&language=en_US) for Salesforce Platform licence

> Users with this license can only view dashboards if the running user also has the same license.

Other Possible Causes.

- The Profile for the Platform Licence users will need to have at least Read permission on the object
- Profile will need run reports privilege

Comment: I logged in as one of the users who is having "Salesforce Platform" license. The user who created the reports have a different profile. The users with the same profile are able to see the report however for different profiles I am getting the error.

Comment: Are those both Platform Licence profiles?

Comment: Nope. They are different

Comment: Check the access to the report folder is there as well as the dashboard folder

Comment: Well, both of em have been granted access. :(

Comment: Hope the user/group of users having "Run Reports" & "Manage Dashboard" permissions and Access to the Dashboard Folder as mentioned by you, its given. 

Secondly, are they able to view any other Dashboard?

Third, Please change the Running User as Logged In User, may be the data is not accessible by the mentioned user.